# Migrating to FuelPHP with existing database

Tags: php, codeigniter, orm, fuelphp

I'm migreting from Codeigniter to FuelPHP. I like Fuel's ORM and other nice stuff and it's really good to enough to start with if you're creating an app from scratch. In my case I have a populated MySQL database and am looking for a right way to use Fuel's ORM and generate controllers, models and views with existing database schema and data. The FuelPHP forum seems to be down for a while and I can't search there. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oil can not be used to reverse engineer an existing database.

But nobody's stopping you from writing your own tasks that will do that, or even simply generate the oil commandline for you based on an existing table layout.

[This task](https://github.com/SicoAnimal/fuel-model-generator) can for example generate models from existing tables...

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I've missed that task but it is really useful even now :)